# C# How to writeline specific string within the string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio-2012, indexof

I'm new to **c#** and I have a little problem. I have the `string`:

```
string file = "Eep_A5000400A_A4000500A$1000219_Mura_20190409003057.eep";

string name1;
string name2;
string name3;
string name4;
```

How to get `string`'s positions

```
  6..12  ->  "5000400" 
 16..22  ->  "4000500"
 33..36  ->  "Mura" 
 53..55  ->  "eep"
```

by using `IndexOf` or `Substring`? (`file` above just an example, `string` inside it may *vary*). For example given, my expectation result is:

```
Console.WriteLine(name1);
Console.WriteLine(name2);
Console.WriteLine(name3);
Console.WriteLine(name4);
```

**Outcome:**

```
5000400
4000500
Mura
eep
```

Do you guys have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name1 = file.Substring(6 - 1, 12 - 6 + 1); name2 = file.Substring(16 - 1, 22 - 16 + 1);` etc. `nameN = file.Substring(startIndex - 1, stopIndex - startIndex + 1);`

Comment: Use substring method : file.SubString(5,7);

Comment: You can use `file.Substring(5, 7)` where the 5 is the start index (indexing begins with 0) and the second one is the length of the Substring.

Answer (score 1):

Simple arithmetics should do:

```
string name = file.Substring(startIndex - 1, stopIndex - startIndex + 1);
```

In your case

```
name1 = file.Substring( 6 - 1, 12 -  6 + 1);
name2 = file.Substring(16 - 1, 22 - 16 + 1);
name3 = file.Substring(33 - 1, 36 - 33 + 1);
name4 = file.Substring(53 - 1, 55 - 53 + 1);
```

You may want to implement an *extension method* for this:

```
  public static partial class StringExtensions {
    public static string FromTo(this string value, int fromIndex, int toIndex) { 
      if (null == value)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
      else if (fromIndex < 1 || fromIndex > value.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fromIndex));
      else if (toIndex < 1 || toIndex > value.Length || toIndex < fromIndex)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(toIndex));

      return value.Substring(fromIndex - 1, toIndex - fromIndex + 1);
    }
  }
```

And then put as simple as

```
  name1 = file.FromTo( 6, 12);
  name2 = file.FromTo(16, 22);
  name3 = file.FromTo(33, 36);
  name4 = file.FromTo(53, 55);
```

Comment: Would disagree with that. When you want to learn to develop, you need to understand that indexing starts at 0 and not at 1. Your solution will cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when using indexing right.

Comment: @bene_rawr: There are no "right" indexing; for instance Delphi, SQL, Basic (and we, human beings) use 1-based indexes. What if all these pairs `6..12`, `16..32` come from some *settings*? It's a cruel to force end users count from `0`

Comment: But we are talking about C#/.NET here. And there indexing starts at 0.

Comment: @bene_rawr: yes, C# uses 0-based indexing; that's why we subtract and add `1`. Imagine that we are given files (like in the question) and asked (by some end user) to extract `6..12`, `16..22` etc fragments for him / her. Shall we *insist* on 0-based (How do you count, guys? Listen, and remember the right order: `0, 1, 2, 3,...` and never `1, 2, 3...` ) or just *be nice* and compute (by adding `-1 / +1`) correct c# indexes

Comment: Depends on the project. With UI you should check for those values, true. But when you write them in code, you should start with the correct index to learn how to handle indexing in C#.

Answer (score 0):

**C# String.Substring method** 
In C# and .NET, a string is represented by the String class. The String.Substring method retrieves a substring from a string instance in C#. The method has the following two overloaded forms.

1. Substring(Int32) - Retrieves a substring from the specified position
   to the end of the string.
2. Substring(Int32, Int32 - Retrieves a substring from this instance
   from the specified position for the specified length.

Therefore, in your case, you can use the following:

```
string file = "Eep_A5000400A_A4000500A$1000219_Mura_20190409003057.eep";
string name1 = file.Substring(6, 7); //6..12  ->  "5000400" 
string name2 = file.Substring(16, 7); //16..22  ->  "4000500"
string name3 = file.Substring(33, 4); //33..36  ->  "Mura" 
string name4 = file.Substring(53, 2); //53..55  ->  "eep"
```